# How add new channels in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Input

# input tensor for a 3-channel 256x256 image
x = Input(shape=(256, 256, 3))
# 3x3 conv with 2 output channels (same as input channels)
y = Conv2D(2, (3, 3), padding='same')(x)
z = keras.layers.add([x, y])
```

I need to create a neural network that not only classifies images, but also counts objects inside it.So, I have to create two channels, is the code above right? How can I train and predict in this case?

Comment: The task you have described is a little more complicated than adding A simple classifier , for reference and simplicity i recommended that you read the function called sliding window , it should be able to perform your tasks

Comment: Thank you, but if the problem not only requires to count the images and classify it, but also extract other features (for example the age), how can I have multi classification?

Comment: Use the output of conv layer for multiple outputs i am assuming with multi class  you will be using soft max so the final loss will be mean square error of your age plus categorical loss from your soft max , you will also have to set your y_true like that

Comment: Thanks. Obviously my network it's more complicated than the code above, but my question was if the last layer it's right: y = Conv2D(2, (3, 3), padding='same')(x)

Comment: Are you using flatten ?

Comment: Yes, after that layer I'll probably do something like this:                                            model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(3,activation='softmax')) Where dense(3..) is why I have to classify cats and dogs and numbers ?

Comment: As a side comment why are you adding the layers , the way I would do this is in the final layer , flatten it , run soft max for classification and one node uses relu or sigmoid , use the losses as specified above

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/slice i believe slice is what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks, but I wonder if it's right the code for a multi classification?

Comment: It should work if that's what you are asking , if you are asking that there are better ways then yes there are

Comment: Thank you so much! For you one of the better ways is slicing right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of after thought it seems to me that what you are trying to achieve is not the main purpose of keras , and while it is entirely possible to do this in keras , creating the custom loss function and maintaining its flow goes out of scope of keras , I recommend that you switch to tensorflow entirely and if needed use the tf.layers for simplicity , I have also created the custom loss function , though i recommend that you try changing it to suite your needs better.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x=np.random.randn(5,5,3)
x=x.reshape(1,*x.shape)
y_val=np.random.randn(1,3)

inputv=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(None,5,5,3))
y=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(None,3))

w=tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1,3,3,1],stddev=0.1),name="W")
b=tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1,shape=[3]),name="B")
conv=tf.nn.conv2d(inputv,w,strides=[1,1,1,1],padding="SAME")
act=tf.nn.relu(conv+b)

flat=tf.contrib.layers.flatten(act)
w1=tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([75,3],stddev=0.1),name="W")
b1=tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1,shape=[3]),name="B")
logits=tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(flat,w1)+b1)

loss=tf.reduce_mean(tf.concat([tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=logits[0][1:],labels=y[0][1:]),tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y[0][0],logits[0][0])],0))
train_step=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(loss)
sess=tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
val=sess.run((logits,loss,train_step),feed_dict={inputv:x,y:y_val})
sess.close()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I had a made a mistake , I had added the tensors instead of concatenation pls correct your code